# Fill date with python pandas asFreq() returns always 1970-01-01

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date, reindex

I wish to fill dates on the interval of dates I have on my dataframe. So I have found `asfreq` command that uses `reindex`. I have tried to use it but no matter how I convert my dates I always have the same answer of `1970-01-01` as on the image attached:

[image]

This is my code:

```
d = pd.DataFrame(data={'col0': [1, 0], 'col1': ['2021-05-07', '2021-05-11'], 'col2': [640, 90]})
d['col1'] = pd.to_datetime(d['col1'])
pd.to_datetime(d.index)
d.asfreq('D')
```

Comment: `d.index=pd.to_datetime(d.index)` then `d.asfreq('D')` as you didn't assign `pd.to_datetime(d.index)` back to the index

Comment: Thank you, I have found at the same time you have replied! :)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested on the replies of question post I needed to add this: `d = d.set_index('col1')`, so the full command will be:
[image]

```
   d = pd.DataFrame(data={'col0': [1, 0], 'col1': ['2021-05-07', '2021-05-11'], 'col2': [640, 90]})
    d['col1'] = pd.to_datetime(d['col1'])
    d = d.set_index('col1')
    pd.to_datetime(d.index)
    d.asfreq('D')
```